# Arrays and pointers in a template

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am attempting to write a template/class that has a few functions, but I'm running into what seems like a rather newbie problem. I have a simple insert function and a display values function, however whenever I attempt to display the value, I always receive what looks like a memory address(but I have no idea), but I would like to receive the value stored (in this particular example, the int 2). I'm not sure how to dereference that to a value, or if I'm just completely messing up. I know that vectors are a better alternative, however I need to use an array in this implementation - and honestly I would like to gain a more thorough understanding of the code and what's going on. Any help as to how to accomplish this task would be greatly appreciated.

Example Output (running the program in the same way every time):
  003358C0

001A58C0

007158C0

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename Comparable>
class Collection
{
public: Collection() {
    currentSize = 0;
    count = 0;
    }
    Comparable * values;
    int currentSize; // internal counter for the number of elements stored
    void insert(Comparable value) {
        currentSize++; 
                // temparray below is used as a way to increase the size of the 
                // values array each time the insert function is called
        Comparable * temparray = new Comparable[currentSize];
        memcpy(temparray,values,sizeof values);

                // Not sure if the commented section below is necessary, 
                // but either way it doesn't run the way I intended

        temparray[currentSize/* * (sizeof Comparable) */] = value; 
        values = temparray;
    }
    void displayValues() {
        for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++) {
            cout << values[i] << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
Collection<int> test;
int inserter = 2;
test.insert(inserter);
test.displayValues();
cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: remember to deallocate the memory `values` points to before insertion (if any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you insist, you can write and debug your own limited version of `std::vector`.

First, don't `memcpy` from an uninitialized pointer. Set `values` to `new Comparable[0]` in the constructor.

Second, `memcpy` the right number of bytes: `(currentSize-1)*sizeof(Comparable)`.

Third, don't `memcpy` at all. That assumes that `Comparable` types can all be copied byte-by-byte, which is a severe limitation in C++. Instead:

EDIT: changed `uninitialized_copy` to `copy`:

```
std::copy(values, values + currentSize - 1, temparray);
```

Fourth, delete the old array when it's no longer in use:

```
delete [] values;
```

Fifth, unless the code is going to make **very few** insertions, expand the array by more than one. `std::vector` typically increases its size by a factor of 1.5.

Sixth, don't increment `currentSize` until the size changes. That will change all those `currentSize-1`s into `currentSize`, which is much less annoying. `<g>`

Seventh, an array of size `N` has indices from `0` to `N-1`, so the top element of the new array is at `currentSize - 1`, not `currentSize`.

Eighth, did I mention, you **really** should use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
memcpy(temparray,values,sizeof values);
```

The first time this line is run, the `values` pointer is uninitialized, so it will cause undefined behavior. Additionally, using `sizeof values` is wrong since that will always give the size of a pointer.

Another issue:

```
temparray[currentSize] = value;
```

This will also cause undefined bahavior because you have only allocated `currentSize` items in `temparray`, so you can only access indices `0` to `currentSize-1`.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an error in your array access.

```
temparray[currentSize/* * (sizeof Comparable) */] = value;
```

Remember that arrays start at index zero.  So for an array of length 1, you would set temparray[0] = value.  Since you increment currentSize at the top of the insert function, you will need to do this instead:

```
temparray[currentSize-1] = value;
```